# JavaScript Quiz with speechrecognition only works with answers in numbers not with words

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to update a quiz game that was built for guessing a number, and make it work it words like "true, false" etc, but it does not work.

If I give it a number like `31`, it works perfectly. However if I change it for text: `correct` it does not identify it as a correct answer.

I'm a student and I'm still learning, what can i do to solve this? Link demo https://codepen.io/joel-martins/pen/KKapOJa

```js
var correct = 31
var trivia = [{
  question: "01. What is CSS?",
  answers: ["Casscading Style Sheets", "Carrot steamed soup", "Corruoted style sheets", "Casscading stairs sheets"],
  correctAnswer: 0
}, ];
const messageElement = document.getElementById("msg");


window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
recognition.start();

function onSpeak(event) {
  const message = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  writeMessage(message);
  checkNumber(message);
}

function writeMessage(message) {
  messageElement.innerHTML = `<div>You said: </div><span class="box">${message}</span>`;
}

function checkNumber(message) {
  const answer = +message;

  if (answer === correct) {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<h2>Congrats! You have guessed the number! <br><br>
      It was ${correct}</h2>
      <button class="play-again" id="play-again">Play Again</button>`;
  } else if (answer !== correct) {
    messageElement.innerHTML += "<div>GO LOWER</div>";
  }
}

// Event Listeners
recognition.addEventListener("result", onSpeak);
recognition.addEventListener("end", () => recognition.start());

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.id == "play-again") 
    history.go(0);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Recursive:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #27273d url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552749412-091909ed9f82?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80") no-repeat center center/cover;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  font-family: "Recursive", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body * {
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.17rem;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

.play-again {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.play-again:hover {
  background-color: #27273d;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.play-again:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.msg {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  margin: 1.25rem;
  padding: 0.625rem;
}


}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/3787/3787697.svg" alt="Speak" />
<h1>Guess a Number Between 1 - 100</h1>
<h2>Speak the number into your microphone</h2>
<div id="msg" class="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Have you given us the right code? It is only looking for a number, I can't see anywhere where the variable called correct is set up to check for a non-numeric answer.

Comment: yes on the top of javascript theres "var correct = 31"